# Yii CListView summary text

Tags: yii

Is there any way to hide "Summary" for CListView without loosing pagination. By summary i mean text like "Displaying 1-2 of 2 result(s).". Or maybe I should use different widget?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following to get more control over the look of your `CListView` output:

```
'template'=>'{items} {pager}'
```

You can even use HTML in the template.

Comment: It's a minor difference but I think this is potentially better than the selected answer because the selected answer will still render an empty `<div class="summary">` whereas with adjusting the template you can completely remove it.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I didn't get it at first, when looking into CListView code, but setting 'summaryText' to '' will do the work. I've realised that second time when I was staring at $summaryText === null

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array( 
     'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider, 
     'summaryText'=>'', 
     'itemView'=>'_indexview',
));
```

Comment: Sorry, where did you set that ?

Comment: $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'summaryText'=>'',
        'itemView'=>'_indexview',)); in views

Answer (score 9):

Here is the example for CListView:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'itemView' => '_view',
'ajaxUpdate' => false,
'emptyText' => 'No records found.',
'summaryText' => "{start} - {end} из {count}",
'template' => '{summary} {sorter} {items} {pager}',
'sorterHeader' => 'Sort by:',
'sortableAttributes' => array('title', 'price'),
'pager' => array(
    'class' => 'CLinkPager',
    'header' => false,
    'cssFile' => '/css/pager.css',
    'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'pager'),
    'maxButtonCount' => '10',
    'prevPageLabel'=>'&larr;',
    'nextPageLabel'=>'&rarr;',
    'header'=>'Pages: ',
),
));
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
'summaryText' => FALSE,
```

Answer (score 1):

You may hide it by adding `CSS` in the page like below.

```
<style>
.summary{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: hiding is not exactly solution I was looking for. It will be still generated

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion

```
  $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $best_seller_data,
        'itemView' => 'alsoBestseller',
    'summaryText'=>false, 
    ));
```