# Changing the Html of CListView Yii

Tags: php, html, yii

I want to change the HTML of my data provided by my CList view when there is a pagination involved.

It shows :

```
Displaying 1-3 of 5 results.
```

At the top of the pagination. I don't want to show that message on the top. What should I do to remove it?

Ex :

[image]

Comment: hide it from css, or set the `summaryText` property to null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is summaryText property
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#summaryText-detail

Hide them in template-detail

```
'template'=>'{items} {pager}'
```

default: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#template-detail

And already was.
[Yii CListView summary text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153316/yii-clistview-summary-text)